# Image replace on hover jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a down arrow image I am trying to replace on hover using jQuery. I have seen examples of solutions using pure CSS with background-image: however I already have a background so not sure if that is an option

I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to make it work

Where am I going wrong?

```js
var currentImage;

$("#contentDiv").hover(function() {
  currentImage = $('img', this).attr("src", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/play-stop-pause/256/Record-Normal-Red-icon.png");
  $('img', this).attr("src", "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/UltimateGnome/256x256/actions/gtk-media-record.png");
}, function() {
  $('img', this).attr("src", currentImage);
});
```

```css
#contentDiv {
  justify-content: center;
  bottom: 2%;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
}

.arrowDown {
  animation: bouncing 2s infinite ease-in-out;
  bottom: 2%;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -25px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentDiv">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/UltimateGnome/256x256/actions/gtk-media-record.png" class="arrowDown" />
</div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan can you explain what you did differently?

Comment: I tried to create a [mcve] for you using the snippet edtior. I did not change your code, only the images

Answer (score 0):

It should be `currentImage = $('img', this).attr("src");` since you are not trying to set the value, but get the value

`$('img', this).attr("src", "whitedot.png")` = Set the value of `src` to `whitedot.png`

`$('img', this).attr("src")` = get the value of the `src` attribute

**Working demo**

```js
var currentImage;

$("#contentDiv").hover(function () {
     currentImage = $('img', this).attr("src");
     $('img', this).attr("src", "reddot.png");
      console.log($('img', this).attr("src"))
}, function () {
     $('img', this).attr("src", currentImage);
      console.log($('img', this).attr("src"))
});
```

```css
#contentDiv {
justify-content: center;
bottom: 2%;
display: block;
height: 50px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -25px;
position: absolute;
width: 50px;
}

.arrowDown {
animation: bouncing 2s infinite ease-in-out;
bottom: 2%;
display: block;
height: 30px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -25px;
position: absolute;
width: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contentDiv">
   <img src="whitedot.png" class="arrowDown"/>              
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for response, this is still not working though

Answer (score 0):

your js syntax for getting attribute value and changing attribute value is wrong. change your js script as

```
var currentImage ="";
$("#contentDiv").hover(function () {
     currentImage = $('img',this).attr("src");
     $('img',this).attr("src", "reddot.png");
}, function () {
     $('img',this).attr("src", currentImage);
});
```

Comment: What's the point of removing `this` from `$("img",this)`? now it will affect all images on the site.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yeah, but as the html posted here, only one img tag is there. Anyway i modified my answer

Comment: There might be other images, the OP might just have include the relevant part of hes code in the snippet

Comment: Thank you for response, this is still not working though

Answer (score 0):

You could use `:hover` and hide the element while showing another:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px silver;
  background-image: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/grey-square-pattern-background-vector-illustration_1164-1350.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
}

.show-on-hover {
  display: none;
}

.hide-on-hover {
  display: inline;
}

div:hover .show-on-hover {
  display: inline;
}

div:hover .hide-on-hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="hide-on-hover" src="https://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/no-image-icon-13.png">
  <img class="show-on-hover" src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_299591.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Of course, the styling depends on whatever @glittergirl 's needs are, but the toggling is achieved in a simple enough way.

Comment: Edited the answer, now it looks better on @mplungjan 's suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do what you wanted but not with the hover function.

here is a function that says hey! when the mouse hovers over me do this function (changeImage)

```
$(function() {
  $("#image1").on("mouseover", changeImage);
});
```

Next we have a function that says When the mouse leaves run this function. (changeImageBack)

```
$(function() {
  $("#image1").on("mouseout", changeImageBack);
});
```

Now we have to make the two functions that we referred to.
The changeImage below takes the src attribute and changes it.

```
function changeImage() {
  $("#image1").attr("src", "rabid_dog.png");
}
```

Lastly when the changeImageBack will change the scr attribute back when the mouse leaves

```
function changeImageBack() {
  $("#image1").attr("src", "me.png");
}
```